# Rails query with nested `where` only if association exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails app, the data model describes a `menu` that has many `menu_items` and a `menu_item` that has many `variants`. Each of the tables has a boolean `visible` attribute.

I'd like to query for all menus, menu items, and variants that are visible.

I've currently got this:

```rb
@menus = Menu.includes(menu_items: [:variants]).where({
  visible: true,
  menu_items: { visible: true },
  variants: { visible: true }
})
```

That filters out non-visible menus, non-visible menu_items, and non-visible variants. However, if a menu_item has no variants, it also gets filtered out.

How can I achieve the filtering on `visible` without losing those menu_items that don't have any variants associated?

Here's the SQL output below:

```sql
SELECT "menus"."id"                    AS t0_r0, 
       "menus"."name"                  AS t0_r1, 
       "menus"."description"           AS t0_r2, 
       "menus"."visible"               AS t0_r3, 
       "menus"."created_at"            AS t0_r4, 
       "menus"."updated_at"            AS t0_r5, 
       "menu_items"."id"               AS t1_r0, 
       "menu_items"."name"             AS t1_r1, 
       "menu_items"."description"      AS t1_r2, 
       "menu_items"."position"         AS t1_r3, 
       "menu_items"."price"            AS t1_r4, 
       "menu_items"."dietary_notes"    AS t1_r5, 
       "menu_items"."visible"          AS t1_r6, 
       "menu_items"."menu_category_id" AS t1_r7, 
       "menu_items"."created_at"       AS t1_r8, 
       "menu_items"."updated_at"       AS t1_r9, 
       "variants"."id"                 AS t2_r0, 
       "variants"."name"               AS t2_r1, 
       "variants"."description"        AS t2_r2, 
       "variants"."dietary_notes"      AS t2_r3, 
       "variants"."visible"            AS t2_r4, 
       "variants"."menu_item_id"       AS t2_r5, 
       "variants"."created_at"         AS t2_r6, 
       "variants"."updated_at"         AS t2_r7, 
       "menu_categories"."id"          AS t3_r0, 
       "menu_categories"."name"        AS t3_r1, 
       "menu_categories"."position"    AS t3_r2, 
       "menu_categories"."description" AS t3_r3, 
       "menu_categories"."created_at"  AS t3_r4, 
       "menu_categories"."updated_at"  AS t3_r5 
FROM   "menus" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "menu_items_menus" 
                    ON "menu_items_menus"."menu_id" = "menus"."id" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "menu_items" 
                    ON "menu_items"."id" = "menu_items_menus"."menu_item_id" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "variants" 
                    ON "variants"."menu_item_id" = "menu_items"."id" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "menu_categories" 
                    ON "menu_categories"."id" = "menu_items"."menu_category_id" 
WHERE  "menus"."visible" = ? 
       AND "menu_items"."visible" = ? 
       AND "variants"."visible" = ?
```

Comment: What about adding `:menu_items` separately in the `includes` statement: `@menus = Menu.includes(:menu_items, menu_items: [:variants])...`

Comment: My SQL isn't great, but I think you want `:menu_items` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `:variants` so you get all `:menu_items` regardless of if they have a variant record. Maybe posting the SQL portion of the terminal output could help.

Comment: Thanks @Chiperific, but unfortunately doing `Menu.includes(:menu_items, menu_items: [:variants])...` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Added the SQL output as an edit above.

Answer (score 0):

```
  has_many :menu_items
  has_many :visible_menu_items, -> {where(visible: true)}, class_name: 'MenuItem'
  ...
end

class MenuItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :variants
  has_many :visible_variants, -> {where(visible: true)}, class_name: 'Variant'
  ...
end
```

Created associations can be used in the query.

`@menus = Menu.eager_load(visible_menu_items: [:visible_variants]).where(visible: true)`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do it for me. In fact, the `visible: true` condition doesn't apply to either menu items or variants when doing this

Comment: @jcjcjcjc Are you using `visible_menu_items` and `visible_variants` instead of  `menu_items` and `variants` in the query. Can you post the SQL query from terminal.